# Problem with incrementing values of an RGB LED

Tags: arduino-uno, ir, rgb-led

I'm trying to use a remote control to control the red/green/blue values of an RGB LED using an Arduino Uno. Here's what I've got so far:

```
#include <IRremote.h>
#define IRPin 7
#define bluePin 9
#define greenPin 10
#define redPin 11

int blueValue = 0;
int greenValue = 0;
int redValue = 0;

IRrecv irrecv(7);
decode_results results;

void RGBLED(int blue, int green, int red)
{
  analogWrite(redPin, red);
  analogWrite(greenPin, green);
  analogWrite(bluePin, blue);
}

void setup(){
  irrecv.enableIRIn();
  pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}


void loop(){
if (irrecv.decode(&results)){
  switch(results.value)
  {
    case 0xFF6897:
      Serial.println("Red+16");
      redValue = redValue + 16;
      if(redValue >= 256)
      {
        redValue = 255;
      }
    break;
    case 0xFF9867:
      Serial.println("Green+16");
      greenValue = greenValue + 16;
      if(greenValue >= 256)
      {
        greenValue = 255;
      }
    break;
    case 0xFFB04F:
      Serial.println("Blue+16");
      blueValue = blueValue + 16;
      if(blueValue >= 256)
      {
        blueValue = 255;
      }
    break;
    case 0xFF30CF:
      Serial.println("Red-16");
      redValue = redValue - 16;
      if(redValue < 0)
      {
        redValue = 0;
      }
    break;
    case 0xFF18E7:
      Serial.println("Green-16");
      greenValue = greenValue - 16;
      if(greenValue < 0)
      {
        greenValue = 0;
      }
    break;
    case 0xFF7A85:
      Serial.println("Blue-16");
      blueValue = blueValue - 16;
      if(blueValue < 0)
      {
        blueValue = 0;
      }
    break;       
  }
irrecv.resume();
RGBLED(blueValue, greenValue, redValue);
}
```

Everything works fine, except the adding up to `redValue`. It's the same exact code that is used for `greenValue` and `blueValue`. The substraction from `redValue` works fine too. Everytime the problematic function gets called, the serial monitor prints `Re` and the whole thing just stops working.
I have tried rewriting that code from scratch, copying the other code, but nothing worked. I have switched up the codes from my IR remote but that had nothing to do with it either.
Can anyone spot the mistakes or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try a short delay and see if that helps

Comment: Try swapping the red `case` with the green case, and see if now the green will give the problem. (i.e. maybe the first `case` somehow breaks things).

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you are using? setup() uses sensorPIN but it does not appear to be declared anywhere.

Comment: @Craig I'm also using a sound sensor as a clap sensor to turn on the LED, but that isn't causing the issue, so I removed it.

Comment: @Gerben I tried switching the two around and the red one is still broken.

Comment: @dandavis adding a short delay after the `Serial.println` makes it so that the message gets printed fully, but it still doesn't work.